# Show that an $n$-connected, $n$-dimensional CW-complex is contractible without invoking Hurewich theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

There is an exercise in section 4.1 of Hatcher:

> Show that an $n$-connected, $n$-dimensional CW-complex is contractible.

I know this can be proved by using the Hurewich theorem from section 4.2 easily (let me know if my argument is wrong):

> If $X$ is $n$-connected then $\pi_k(X)~\text{for}~ k=0,\cdots, n$. 
>   Since $X$ is an $n$-dimensional CW complex, $H_k(X)=0$ when $k\ge n+1$.
>   By using Hurewich theorem (Theorem 4.32) inductively, we have  $\pi_{k}(X)=H_{k}(X)=0$ for $k>n$. Then it follows from the [Whitehead theorem](https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf#page=355#) that $X$ is contractible.

My question is: since this problem is given before the section for Hurwich theorem, is there an approach by using only the knowledge in section 4.1 of Hatcher?

Comment: What version of Whitehead are you using? It sounds like you are using the usually corollary (which comes from Hurewicz) of the standard Whitehead theorem.

Comment: @PVAL-inactive The version I am using is theorem 4.5(page 346) of his book, which is proved before the Hurwich theorem(4.32)

Comment: Alright so then what do you need Hurewicz for? You do understand that $\pi_k(X)$ trivial IS the definition of n-connected?

Comment: @PVAL-inactive I was trying to show that $\pi_{k}(X)=H_{k}(X)=0$ for $k>n$. Yes, the condition says $\pi_{k}(X)=0$ for $k\le n$, after showing that all homotopy groups are trivial, I can use the whitehead theorem to prove that $X$ is contractible

Comment: You build the contraction by hand, as in the proof of Whitehead.

Comment: Use CW approximation and cellular approximation. Then you can get a homotopy between $X$ and a point.

Answer (score 0):

Using Contraction Lemma, set $Y=X$, $B=x_0$.
By the lemma, any map (including identity of X) should homotopic to the constant map. Thus it is contractible.

Comment: This is called a **compression lemma** (in Hatcher, used in the proof of Whitehead's theorem).  Including the statement or a reference into the answer would help.  However, i do not see why this answer is downvoted.  Those who downvote, could you leave some comments?